# Image not displayed when using html2fpdf

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

This is a long shot but here goes....

We've an application that has been on the go for many years. We've recently upgraded the framework version that it runs on (to Codeigniter 2.2.6) and the PHP version (to v5.6). Since the upgrade one of the older features has caused an issue. It concerns the html2fpdf library (about 10 years old at this stage!). The library is a wrapper for fpdf and as the name suggests takes html input and allows output to an fpdf document. Nearly all things work fine, except embedded images / jpegs. For instance the following html:

```
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="120">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="500"><img src="https://acorn.rentproapp.com/www/images/acorn-logo-new-large.jpg" alt="" width="500" align="middle" /></td>
<td width="120">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Resukts in the following output in the PDF document

Â»Â¤Â¬type=image,width=132.25,height=51.862745098Â»Â¤Â¬q 374.88 0
0 147.01 28.35 553.14 cm /I1 Do Q

However, if I were to strip all HTML tags, bar the image source, i.e.

```
<img src="https://acorn.rentproapp.com/www/images/acorn-logo-new-large.jpg" alt="" width="500" align="middle" />
```

then the image is correctly displayed within the PDF.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the encoding of the html2fpdf.php file. Copy the file exactly as you extracted it from the original zip file.